# Short permanent file URL in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

A complete WP newbie here...

I want to upload file to the WP site, so users can download it.
From what I see, when uploading to WP, the file gets a long URL which includes wp-content, date, etc. I want it to have a short, permanent URL, ie:

```
www.mysite.com/setup/setup.exe
```

How can I do that?

Please note this question applies to only one or two files on my site, the rest of the files (images, mainly) can continue use the same URL scheme.

Thanks!

Comment: the easiest way would be to create a folder "setup" and upload the file with your ftp client.

Comment: Following my "complete newbie" status... How do I add a folder in WP? Can't find it in the wp-admin pages?

Comment: This is completely unrelated to WordPress. Create a folder with your FTP program, upload your file, done.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks for the help! Please post an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder in your ftp where the site is hosted, call it `Download` then your file will be available at: `www.mysite.com/download/file.me`